# Does an always running foreground service affect play store auto update?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

I have an app that has an always running foreground service (restarts itself if it is killed) that uses BLE. We installed it on some tablets that are connected to wifi and cell, can update over any network, and auto updates are enabled.

The problem is, the tablets have versions from almost 4 weeks ago running on them despite publishing 4-5 new versions since then. Other apps are updating. Why isn't my app updating?

The tablets are on Android versions 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you get more info?

Comment: Yes. It does affect updates, from what we have gathered. nothing will update if you have an always running service. You should listen to if there is an update available or not (see https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates ). We toggle our service off during a few down time hours.

Comment: We tested around 7 devices for 2 weeks and got about 70% to update with a 6 hour downtime window each night. I wish my bosses let me just prompt the users to update. Using the API above, you can do that.